# Browser Video Player sometimes not Displaying Right Colors

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, video, browser, colors

This just started, around the same time Youtube updated their site UI. The problem only happens with media players like Youtube's, its doesn't appear to affect Netflix and sites like theirs, with an independent media player. I haven't updated anything at all, but when using Google Chrome(I don't know about any other browser) the blue and red colors on web video players are very low. I can still make out a little bit of color, but the green is usually very prominent, it looks more like black and white color though.

I'm using 32-bit Windows 10 and have already tried to fix it using browser settings(at least those I know about), Windows Display Calibration, and restarting the browser/computer.